# Keep a value the same on chrome extension

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extension

Hello

I'm having some issues with my extension, I made a radio player which works, but I added a volume control, and when for example you slide the slider to 25% of the volume, the volume of the audio gets down to 25%, but when you close the popup and then open the popup again, the slider is at 100% and the volume of the audio at 25%.


So what I'm trying to do is:

keeping the slider at the value that it was when the popup gets closed, so when the user open the popup again the value of the slider will still be 25% and not back to 100%

---

Code:

**popup.html:**

```
<a class="playback" href="#">
<img id="play" src="img/play.png" />
</a>

<div class="mutebtns">
<a id="mute-bt" href="#">
<img id="mute" rel='tipsy' src="img/unmuted.png" title="Mute" />
</a>
</div>

<div stle="display:inline;">Volume:<span id="val"></span></div>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

**script.js:**

```
var bgPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

    // Volume control
    $(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
    animate: "true",
    value : 100,
    step  : 1,
    range : 'min',
    min   : 0,
    max   : 100,
    slide : function( event, ui ){
      var value = $("#slider").slider("value");
        bgPage.$("#audio_player")[0].volume = parseFloat(value / 100);
      $("#val").html(ui.value + "%");
    }
    });
        $("#val").html($("#slider").slider("value") + "%");
    });
```

**background.html:**

```
<div id="audiocontainer">
    <audio id="audio_player" src="http://85.25.118.16:7502/;livestream.mp3" width="320" height="80"></audio>
    <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the actual volume directly from the `<audio>` element at the background page instead of the unrelated value at the slider:

```
$("#val").text(bgPage.$("#audio_player")[0].volume * 100 + "%");
```

If you want to persist the settings, consider saving the value in `localStorage`:

```
  slide : function( event, ui ){
    var value = $("#slider").slider("value");
    bgPage.$("#audio_player")[0].volume = parseFloat(value / 100);
    localStorage.setItem('volume', value);
    $("#val").html(ui.value + "%");
  }
});
var volume = localStorage.getItem('volume');
if (volume == null) {
    // Not saved yet, use default value
    volume = 100; // 100%
}
$("#val").text(volume + '%');

// And in the background page:
// After creating the <audio> element:
var volume = localStorage.getItem('volume');
if (volume == null) {
    // Not saved yet, use default value
    volume = 100; // 100%
}
audioElement.volume = volume / 100;
```

Instead of repeating the same code for getting the volume, I recommend to create a function for it. That makes it easier to maintain your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Your code works partially, the value stays, but it shows value +1, like if you set the slider at 50%, close and open the popup, it will show 51%, and the slider always gets back to full, it doesn't stay at 50%.. I've been trying to figure this out the whole night and still can't find how to do :(

Comment: @NexsHax Can you show an example of failure, preferrably in http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: This is when you open the popup for the first time and drag the volume: [link](http://i.imgur.com/3BA2b.png) ---

And this is when you close the popup and then open it again: [link](http://i.imgur.com/RNSdl.png) ---

As you can see the value is -1 and the slider is complete..

Comment: @NexsHax The slider's size can easily be solved by replacing the `value: 100` configuration property with something more sensible, eg `value: +volume` (assuming that volume is a valid number). I don't know how to fix 16->17 without seeing the relevant code, please set up a http://jsfiddle.net/ for it.

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gLsg3/) --- I wasn't sure if I had to remove the bg page code and relative or not so I kept it as it was..

Comment: @NexsHax Sorry, I don't have enough time to turn that broken fiddle in something useful. Please show a working fiddle which shows your problem (apparently an unwanted +1 of the value).

Comment: @NexsHax Use `var value = ui.value;` instead of `value = $('#slider').slider('value');`. `ui.value` represents the expected value, whereas `.slider('value')` returns the value of the slider before it slides. See also the jQuery UI docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide; final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YmYg3/2/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the slider's value to 100, put it to the current volume.

```
value: $('#slider')[0].volume,
```

Comment: Not working :/ the slider is at 0, the volume at 100, and when I close and open the popup, the slider is back to 0..